# Python - extracting a SQL Server database schema to a file

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, database-schema

Often I need to extract the complete schema of an existing SQL Server DB to a file.  I need to cover every object -- tables, views, functions, SPs, UDDTs, triggers, etc.  The purpose is so that I can then use a file-diff utility to compare that schema to a baseline reference.

Normally I use Enterprise Manager or Management Studio to script out the DB objects and then concatenate those files to make one big file in a consistent predictable order.  I was wondering whether there's a way to accomplish this task in Python?  Obviously it'd take an additional package, but having looked at a few (pyodbc, SQLAlchemy, SQLObject), none of them seem really suited to this use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can connect to SQL Server and run queries in Python then yes – it’s possible but it will take a lot of effort and testing to get it to work correctly.

Idea is to use system tables to get details about each object and then generate DDL statements based on this. Some if not all DDL statements already exist in sys.syscomments table.

Start off by executing and examining this in SSMS before you start working in Python.

```
select *
from sys.tables

select *
from sys.all_columns

select *
from sys.views

select *
from sys.syscomments
```

All system tables [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260604%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

I've used this PowerShell strategy in the past.  Obviously, that isn't Python, but it is a script you can write then execute from within Python.  Give this article a read as it may be your easiest (and cheapest) solution: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/04/use-powershell-to-script-sql-database-objects.aspx

As a disclaimer, I was only exporting stored procedures, not every single object.

Comment: Actually I like this approach better on the whole than the other answer, but the PowerShell learning curve is a sticking point for me.  For now I'll be using the Python option, but down the road I may switch over.